# Setting a resource for Spring Batch reader from file system

Tags: java, spring, classpath, spring-batch

I'd like to adjust my code to make the `Spring Batch reader` to read the resource file not from class path, but from the file system (like C:\inputData.xml). Is there any way, how to make it? My current code looks like this and reads given `xml` file from resources folder just fine:

```
@Bean
ItemReader<FamilyBatchEntity> xmlFamilyFileItemReader() {
    StaxEventItemReader<FamilyBatchEntity> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
    xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("inputData.xml"));
    xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Familiendetails");

    Jaxb2Marshaller insurantMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    insurantMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(FamilyBatchEntity.class);
    xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(insurantMarshaller);

    return xmlFileReader;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `ClassPathResource` to a `FileSystemResource` and pass in the path.  You can read more about the `FileSystemResource` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html